# Excel VBA - Selecting multiple options for each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use some VBA code for a column in data set to give the user option to select one or more answer for all cells in that column. For example, say column A represent my data types and the options users will have are:

```
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3
Type 4
Type 5
```

Now I would like to code this somehow so that every time user select any cell on Column A pop up box appears with the 5 options where user can select one or more types and press ok which will store the information in the cell.

For example if the user selection Type 1,2 and 3 in Cell A2 I want the cell A2 to show “Type A1, Type A2 and Type A3”

I am just wondering if this is possible at all with VBA and any advise towards how I should approach this would be really useful.

Comment: You can cut out VBA; go to Data > Data Validation, Allow: List, then type your list or enter a range in which your list is specified

Comment: This only allow me to select one option and I would like to select multiple options if possible

Comment: In that case I misunderstood what you meant, I suppose you could put all possible combinations into the list, but I'd go with daZza's solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible, however, permanently popping up boxes when people click a cell will probably get on their nerves rather quickly.

You'll need to create a custom user form first.

Then, to trigger an action for each cell in a column, use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
UserForm1.Show 'Your custom user form

End If

End Sub
```

Depending on what kind of objects you use in your user form you'll need to implement the appropriate `_Click` or similar function to check which checkboxes or whatever elements you used the user checked.

For a Checkbox this would be:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
'Do stuff, i.e. write the selection to your cell or whatever
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I have a good idea now how I should approach with this. many thanks